# Downloading file from S3 and redirect with cURL

Tags: curl, amazon-s3

I'm trying to programatically download a zip file from a secured bucket on S3, and once the download is sent to the browser I want a receipt page to be shown.

But I keep getting all kinds of crazy characters that are being output to the browser instead:

```
$url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/{$bucket}/{$resource}?{$authentication_params}";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('response-content-type: application/zip', 'response-content-disposition: attachment', 'Expect: 100-continue'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

If I type `$url` in the address bar in firefox, the download works. How do I download the file and then continue to my receipt page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up simply reversing the order of my process and using a meta refresh header for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the destination filename with an extension to download the zip files correctly.

So for instance if you want to download a zip file located at www.url.com/myzip.zip, you'll need to provide the -o parameter with the destination filename.

-o tells curl to save the downloaded contents to a file, without this parameter, curl will simply display the file contents, in your case the binary.

example:
`curl -o dave.zip https://www.url.com/myzip.zip`

Comment: `$url` is currently set to `"https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.zip?{$authentication_params}";` and i'm still having the issues above.

Comment: sorry for being a bit lazy, updated my answer, hope it helps now

Comment: what does -o translate to in php?

Comment: -o stands for output.  this option tells curl to write the file contents of the downloading file to a file and not stdout.

Comment: thanks - I don't want to write the file contents to a file on the server, though. i want to send it to the browser and then send the user to a confirmation page...

Comment: o, your question's a bit misleading in that case.

Comment: why not just have a link to the zipped folder you want your users to download?

Comment: I'm selling protected downloads, so I need authentication